# DateTime.TryParseExact is working but returns false

Tags: c#

This is a very strange occurrence where DateTime.TryParseExact is working but returns false and the same code on another windows machine is returning true. I just can't get my head round why this is happening.
The code is fine but returns false and true on different machines

```
string dateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
DateTime dateTime;
string bst = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateAndTime);
var check = DateTime.TryParseExact(bst, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString(dateAndTime);` wut? `dateAndTime` is `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");`. That's the current time formatted as a string, and not a string format you can used to format a DateTime

Comment: Despite the fact, that your _dateAndTime_ string is NOT a valid time format, you also don't provide a format provider to your third line, meaning it uses the culture of the machine. If that differs between your two machines, you know the reason why it behaves differently.

Comment: Try this: `string bst = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");`

Comment: `string bst = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateAndTime);` - `dateAndTime` is a string _value_ of a date/time, not a _format_, so it is nonsense. What makes you think that `TryParseExact` is "working" in this case?

Comment: My guess is that sometimes `dateAndTime` has no format codes and just echoes back the string value, and sometimes results in an invalid format specifier

Comment: Pull out your debugger.  Step through the first line and stop.  Look at `dateAndTime`.  On my machine, right now and right here, it looks like: `"24/08/2023 10:03"`.  Now look at the third line.  You pass that literal date and time string in as the format string in a call to `DateTime.ToString(string format)`.  I think what you meant to write was the first line followed immediately by: `var check = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateAndTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTime);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string dateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
var check = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateAndTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTime);
```

In your original code, you (effectively) have:

```
string dateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
string bst = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateAndTime);
```

After the first line executes, `dateAndTime` is going to look something like: `"24/08/2023 10:03"`.  That's not a format string that you can pass to `DateTime.ToString (string format)`.  I have no idea what `bst` is going to look like - it may simply be `"24/08/2023 10:03"`.  Getting rid of that line (and not using `bst`) is very likely to make your code behave the way you expect.

Comment: Your code makes no difference. The code I posted above returns false on one windows machine and returns returns on another windows machine and I just can get why there are two results to the same code on two windows machines